# Prevent .NET code from calling particular methods?

Tags: .net, compiler-errors, fxcop

Is there a way to create compile time errors if a certain method is called?

As an example, what I'd like to do is prevent code in a certain project from calling System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings().  Is there a way to tag the project or class file to raise a compile time error IF that method is called?

I don't think there is, so my thought is that the only way to do this is to generate an FxCop rule that would flag these calls and do it that way, but I am open to other ideas.

I am using .NET 3.5.  Not sure if 4.0 code contracts can do this.

## Updates

I am specifically talking about framework methods, not my own, so I cannot mark them as Obsolete.

At this point I don't care about reflection.

Another example is System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode, which I want to find and replace with Microsoft's AntiXss library, but I'd like to integrate some sort of check process on my build server that would check new code as well.

Comment: Do you want to disallow calling this method through reflection, too?

Comment: If it was your own assemblies and you can recompile you can use the Obsolete attribute, if that helps at all.

Comment: Why is there to begin with if you don't want them using it?

Comment: @AustinSalonen, it appears this is about a Framework method.

Comment: @svick:  Given _that_ framework method, you have to add a specific reference so the question still stands.

Comment: Please see my updates.  I am talking about Framework methods, so I cannot mark as obsolete.

Comment: Just an idea - you can check if it is possible to **mock** the forbidden method so it throws exception. Not sure which mocking frameworks support such scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool [NDepend](http://www.NDepend.com) can be used for that (*Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the tool*).

You can write some [Code Rules over LINQ Queries (CQLinq)](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL) to check any kind of dependency, like a method call for example. Code rules can be [checked in Visual Studio](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_CQL.aspx) after each successful compilation, or [rules can be checked at build process time](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_Report.aspx#CQLRule) as well.

Such a CQLinq code rule can look like:

```
warnif count > 0 
from m in Application.Methods         
where m.IsUsing("System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings()")
select m
```

The rule can be specialized at whim, to forbid for example namespaces that match a regex, to contain methods that call the `get_AppSettings()` getter method:

```
warnif count > 0 
from m in Application.Namespaces.WithNameLike("regex").ChildMethods()
where m.IsUsing("System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings()")
select m
```

From the NDepend [dependency matrix](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_Matrix.aspx) or [dependency graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx), you can also right click a dependency (matrix cell or graph arrow) and generate a code rule that warns if the dependency exist (and then specialize the rule generated if you need):

[image]

Comment: I've only ever used the NDepend UI.  I'll have to check if I can integrate it into our CruiseControl.NET/NAnt build scripts.  Is that possible?

Comment: Yes this is possible, read our CC.NET integration related doc: http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_CCNet.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You are able to [write your own rules in FxCop](http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/html/index.html) so perhaps that's an option.

However, in this case, for existing code-base you might find that a Ctrl-F (Find) in your editor for "ConfigurationManager.AppSettings" might do an equally good job with far less effort... With regards to future enforcement though you might consider a more human route of an email memo to the development team...

As highlighted by a commenter above and worth noting for others with similar goals, is that if this were referring to a function in your own code-base (which this question is *not* referring to), you could use the `[Obsolete]` attribute.

Comment: While I agree that an email **should** work, I'd like something a little more concrete in terms of validation.

Comment: Maybe tell the team they owe a 6-pack of beer to the rest of the team for breaking coding standards!? In all seriousness, FxCop with a custom rule will help you validate it, but that's only as long as the dev's (or a build server) install the rule(s) and use FxCop properly...